# static method throws NullPointerException when I try to access it inside thread

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-mvc

Here I've got a thread

```
@Component("sessionStateListenerThread")
public class SessionStateListenerThread extends Thread {

    private static final String DEFAULT_RESULT = "expired";
    private List<DeferredResult<String>> subscribed = Collections
            .synchronizedList(new ArrayList<DeferredResult<String>>());

    /**
     * Main thread loop for checking session state.
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (subscribed) {
                try {
                    if (null == SecurityHelper.getUserLogin()) {
                        Iterator<DeferredResult<String>> it = subscribed.iterator();
                        while (it.hasNext()) {
                            DeferredResult<String> result = it.next();
                            result.setResult(DEFAULT_RESULT);
                            it.remove();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adds client to listen session state.
     *
     * @param client
     */
    public void addClient(DeferredResult<String> client) {
        synchronized (subscribed) {
            subscribed.add(client);
        }
    };
}
```

This class is used to wrap that thread

```
@Component
@DependsOn("sessionStateListenerThread")
public class SessionStateListener {

    @Autowired
    private SessionStateListenerThread thread;

    @PostConstruct
    public void configThread() {
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.setName("SessionStateChecker");
    }

    /**
     * Starts listener.
     */
    public void startListener() {
        thread.start();
    }

    /**
     * Adds client to write result.
     *
     * @param client object to write result
     */
    public void addSessionStateListener(DeferredResult<String> client) {
        thread.addClient(client);
    }
}
```

I put method `startListener` inside controller method. Also in controller I access method `getUserLogin`.

```
String login = SecurityHelper.getUserLogin(); // successfully access it

listener.startListener();
```

Method `run` in thread want to access this method `getUserLogin` too. 
But despite `login` value being not null - invokation of `SecurityHelper.getUserLogin()` throws `NullPointerException` inside thread.

What's the problem? `getUserLogin` looks like this

```
return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
```

Stacktrace is somehow small (`e.printstacktrace()`)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ui.web.security.SecurityHelper.getUserLogin(SecurityHelper.java:45)
        at com.ui.web.controller.rest.poll.SessionStateListenerThread.run(SessionState
ListenerThread.java:41)
```

Comment: It would be much easier to debug `NullPointerException` if we have the stacktrace and the line on which the exception occurs.

Comment: ya I got it...:) I didn't see you had put that code already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you can't get current session data (context) into separate thread than current request thread.

You will be able to get any session data into any controller method, because any controller method will be executed within request thread.

Comment: You can't get it, but I am not getting why did you create the thread `SessionStateListenerThread` ? What should be it's purpose in your app?

Comment: Long polling session tracking -> UI wait for invalidated session in order to ask or force page reload. Originally it was anonymous class but I decided to move it into separate class.